# Inconsistent System of Linear Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A ∈ M_{n\times n}(F)$. Suppose that the system of linear equations $AX = B$
has more than one solution. Prove that there is a column $C ∈ F^n$ such that
the system of linear equations $AX = C$ is inconsistent.

I thought it'd be clever to use this (underlined by my pencil):

[image]

Comment: I suspect that there are can be more than one such $C$.

Comment: I apologize for being off-topic, but what is this pencil? Not the usual Staedtler lead holder. The brand is perfectly obscured.

Comment: @CommonerG It's OK. I'm not a member of the scope gestapo. It's CARAN d'ACHE. It's very durable. You have to buy graphite rods in bulk. This pencil, I believe, will last your entire life. If you find out a place to buy clip replacements, let me know because I can't find any. It's the FIXPENCIL 3 METAL type. Also, and I hate to sound like I'm trying to sell this thing to you, but the end piece is the sharpener, very self-contained.

Comment: @CommonerG Kind of a Ship of Thesus moment...

Comment: I mean Theseus not Thesus. I wouldn't want to be on a thesis ship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: What does the premise imply about the kernel of $A$? Also:

$$\dim(\text{Im } A)+\dim(\ker A)=n.$$

Comment: Happy it's of any use.

Comment: I wasn't approaching it in the dimension-theorem direction, but I'll try to see it that way.

Comment: Are you saying that $\dim \text{span}(\{a_1,\dots,a_n\})=\dim \text{span}(\{a_1,\dots,a_n,\bar{\sigma_1},\bar{\sigma_2}\})$ where the $a_i$'s are the columns of $A$ and the $\bar{\sigma_i}$'s are two solutions to $AX=B$?

Comment: Let $x_1$ denote the first solution and $x_2$ the second. Then, $A(x_1-x_2)=Ax_1-Ax_2=B-B=0$. So, $\dim(\ker A)\geq 1$ which implies that $\dim($Im $A)<n$. In other words span$(\{a_1,\dots,a_n\})\neq F^n$. Does this clear things up?

Comment: OK, I've got that here.

Comment: What about the infinite solution set case?

Comment: hmm (I was assuming $n$ was finite), I can't tell you for certain there (dealt very little with infinite dimensional spaces). However, the result used still holds (using rank and nullity instead of dim(ker()) and dim(Im())) see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

Comment: How can $\dim (\ker{A})$ be equal to $1$ if it has more than one solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8763/discussion-between-jkn-and-trancot)

Comment: Oh, OK. So $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ is a linearly dependent set, so if $Y$ and $Y'$ are two solutions to $AX=B$ then for each we must have that at least one $y_i$ in the column $\begin{pmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n \end{pmatrix}$ or $y'_i$ in the column $\begin{pmatrix} y'_1 \\ y'_2 \\ \vdots \\ y'_n \end{pmatrix}$ to be nonzero, so... I don't know if this is leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

---

***Lemma:*** Let $AX=C$ be a system of linear equations. Then the system is consistent if and only if $\text{dim Im}~(A)=\text{dim Im}~(A \mid C)$.

---

Let $Y$ and $Y'$ be solutions to the system $AX=B$. Then

$$ A(Y) = A(Y')=B,$$

or

$$ A(Y)-A(Y')=A(Y-Y')=0,$$

so $\dim \text{Ker}~(A)\geq 1$, which means $\dim \text{Im}~(A)<n$, or simply that

$$\text{span}~(\{A^{(1)},\dots,A^{(n)}\})\neq F^n.$$

In other words, there exists at least one $A^{(i)}$ such that

$$A^{(i)}=k_1A^{(1)}+\cdots +k_{i-1}A^{(i-1)}+k_{i+1}A^{(i+1)}+\cdots + k_nA^{(n)}\neq ce_i,$$

for some $e_i\in \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ the standard basis for $F^n$ with $k_i,c\in F$. Thus, by the lemma, we clearly see that such an $e_i$ is the desired $C$ for which $AX=C$ has no solutions, namely

$$\text{dim Im}~(A)\neq \text{dim Im}(A \mid e_i)=\text{dim Im}(A \mid C).$$

This is so because if $\text{dim Im}(A)=m$, then $\text{dim Im}~(A \mid e_i)=m+1$ for such an $e_i$ described above.

Comment: @jkn What do you think?

Comment: I think that your reasoning is correct. However I'm unsure about the "In other words, there exists..." step. I think you can just argue that: Im$(A)$=span$(\{A^1,\dots,A^n\})\neq F^n$ implies that there exists some $C\in F^n$ such that $C\not\in$Im$(A)$. Hence, dim Im$(A)$<dim Im$(A|C)$. The Lemma then gives you the desired result.

Comment: @jkn Check my recent edit.